# What's the Concept of local database of sql server in .net

Tags: c#, sql-server

Let's suppose I made an application in .net using sql server as database.
So if I want to deploy my application to some another PC i have to instal sql server 
but I want that i should not install the sql server and my database should be automatically installed
i just want to make sure that is the concept of Local Database can fulfill my requirement 
if so then how is it possible for me 
thanks

Comment: Having a locally private database may only be a good decision dependent on the type of data being accessed (bank records, audits and so on). In order to keep said mdf data secure you would require have to have some sort of full time encryption (there is a lot of work in maintaining a local database).

Answer (score 1):

You should run your SQL server on a separate computer (server) to avoid having to install SQL server on all client computers. This way all PCs running your application can share a single instance of SQL Server.

If you want a single user DB per application instance I would recommend using SQL Compact edition instead

Comment: i know that but i want to deploy my application without sql server

Comment: Yes, you will be able to do that since the application is pointing to a shared SQL Server instance

Comment: I believe the OP wishes to deploy the app to users who have no SQL Server instance to point to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use App_Data folder in the visual studio to store your .mdf files.Once you transfer your solution to a different system , the db file will be transferred automatically.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx

Comment: how can i create this folder in windows application

Comment: please go through this post - very similar to your situation
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/08abd02f-30b6-4b07-a615-9bc87cfc79c4

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL2012 Express Edition LocalDB. This uses a self contained file for your database, and can be installed as a prerequisite. When your application installs, you can install a blank database file, and connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is not a small application that will be installed automatically and will require setup and configuration. You can however use it remotely. Or consider using an embedded database. But if you want to use a local database, you can use your `mdf` file of the database as a local database.

Comment: but in local database most of the features are not supported like procedures i.e

Comment: I think local database support sdf file not mdf file

Comment: Nope, you can use mdf files. Check this out : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233763.aspx